# Using foreach loop with DataList on Page Load

Tags: c#, foreach, datalist, pageload

I am working with a datalist on one of my pages, while trying to find the controls using a foreach loop it does not go into the loop.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (DataListItem dli in shoplistview.Items)
        {
            string productID = ((Label)dli.FindControl("lblProductID")).Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Is the datalist not in the current runtime when !IsPostBack? Or is there something I am missing here? If you need any additional info I can try to include it. I appreciate any advice you can offer to me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Check if `shoplistview.Items.Count == 0`

Comment: returns true... And this solves it for me, was calling the loop before anything was populated in the list. I moved the foreach loop and it works. Thanks for the boost to get me unstuck!

Comment: maybe @oleksii should add that as an answer so it can be accepted as an answer of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `shoplistview.Items.Count == 0` seems like an empty data source.

Answer (score 2):

Bind Datalist[shoplistview] before the for Loop

Comment: Assign DataSource to shoplistview before the for Loop

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any items in your shoplistview? - you can check the count of the collection at this point to see what it contains.